# Analysis for a Within-Subjects Design with Ordinal IV and Continuous DV

Tags: nonparametric, ordinal-data, friedman-test

I have a set of non-normal data I'm trying to analyse but am worried I'm violating the assumptions of my chosen test. I have a 18-trial within subjects experimental design. Participants received an accuracy score for each trial (0, .25, .5, .75, 1) and I want to see if there is a difference among a continuous DV based on their accuracy. For example, I want to see if when participants had a score of 1 if the DV was higher than when participants received a score of 0.25.

I believe I need to run a Friedman's test, however I can't assume it's a true repeated measures. Each participant doesn't necessarily have a DV value for each accuracy score. Is there something I can do like a Jonckheere-Terpstra test that would account for the same participants (but not truly matched) belonging to each ordinal rank?